# How to implement a job queue system?

Tags: c#, ai

Essentially I'm trying to make a system which you can add a job to it then finds an AI which is idle and gives it that job to do, For an example look at Prison Architects job list system (image below).

[image: Prison Architect Job system]

I need to be able to add a job, removed them and look at all the jobs. The next job that this returns should be the oldest one in the list.

Initially I thought of using a queue as it already provides adding and removing but as it turns out I can only see the next item in that list (well at least thats the case with the standard C# implementation of it), meaning that if there is a certain requirement which isn't met I can't skip to the next task.

Is there a version of the queue that exposes all the items within the list or some other way of doing something similar? This will be coded in C# if that makes difference to the options available.

Comment: By the way: the queue in prison architect is not pure first-in-first-out. For example, when the player gives an explicit order they are prioritized over automatically generated jobs, build jobs appear to be actually first-in-last-out and workers seem to prioritize jobs which are nearby. A pure FIFO data structure will likely turn out to be too restraining and inflexible in the long run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The job queue system in Prison Architect is actually far more complex than a pure first-in-first-out queue. Actors prioritize their jobs:

- They only take jobs they are actually qualified for (example: any staff member can perform the "open staff door" job, but only guards can do the "open jail door" job)
- In many cases they prioritize jobs given by the player over jobs generated automatically
- They often prioritize jobs which are nearby over those which require some walking
- In other situations they prioritize the jobs which were generated first. It seems like distance and age are somehow valued against each other.
- Some jobs immediately spring to the front. For example, guards will stop doing what they do when they witness a prisoner misbehaving.

I could imagine that the developers started out with a simple FIFO queue for their job system, but then realized that it is far too inflexible to allow actors to behave as efficiently as the player would expect it. I would recommend you to just store all jobs unsorted in an `ArrayList` or similar unsorted data-structure. When an actor needs a new job, it iterates that whole datastructure and uses a rating function to assign an *own* priority rating to each job and pick the job with the highest score *for itself*.

Comment: I know that it is more complex but for now at least there are no auto generated tasks (for now) so I guess that this will probably be the better thing to do in the long run. For now Im using a dictionary and just looking for the first not used job that is in the queue, this is run on another thread so once I figure out a rating system FPS shouldn't be affected which is nice :)  I will look back on this once I have more time to work on the project...

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be adding and removing tasks dynamically, and they may have differing times, then you may want to look at a C# implementation of a  Priority Queue.

It's a pretty basic data structure and implementations will be easy to find based on trees (usually red-black) or heaps.

Access to the next available is O(1) and insertions in most implementations will be O(log n) which is pretty fast indeed.

Comment: Priority Queue could be not such a good solution if each agents has its own priorities (distance, qualification, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `List<T>` instead. See [How to add item to the beginning of `List<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390491/how-to-add-item-to-the-beginning-of-listt) for adding to front.

Not the most efficient but the Job Queue won't be the bottleneck in your game.

Alternatively, you can use a `LinkedList<T>` and wrap it in your own `JobQueue` class, here's a post showing how: [Is there a better way to implement a remove method for a queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594375/is-there-a-better-way-to-implement-a-remove-method-for-a-queue). This option is less cache performant but you can add/remove anywhere in the list.

Comment: I'll look into it, thanks. I had an idea and I might just work around a hash table... :)

Comment: A Hash Table is the wrong choice here since it is not a sequence container.

Comment: Remark also that there is a [`Queue<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx "Link to MSDN site") object in C#

Comment: @luis op noted in the question that queue can't remove anything but the head of queue so it doesn't help his use case.