# How do I design a "Chores" or "Errands" system?

Tags: architecture, ai, entity

I have a number of entities running around in my game, and I am running into a headache trying to design and implement a system for them to both generate and assign the tasks. More than anything else, I think I'm running into a vocabulary issue, as it's very hard to research the system I am trying to design. At any rate, here's the terminology that *I'm* using.

**Entity**

Hopefully self-explanatory

**Chore / Errand**

Something that an Entity can perform in game, such as "move these crates from A to B", or, "Perform Y at building Z until X". Chores have priority (some are more important), exclusivity (only one entity can be performing a specific chore), and (potentially) requirements (only entities with Forklift certification can perform this job).

[This question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/114078/how-to-implement-a-job-queue-system) has an excellent example, despite being unrelated to my personal difficulties.

---

The main points of concern for me are Chore generation and assignation. In both instances, can see a case for either a single centralized hub which can respond to a "getNextTask" function (such as Prison Architect's "Jobs" list), or an event-based, decentralized approach where an entity sends a "LookingForWork" event, and the individual chores themselves respond as available (or not!) depending on the event parameters.

This gets geometrically more complex when you start to consider that tasks can be interrupted, paused, resumed, or cancelled.

This is (clearly) not a novel problem space, but I'm not sure how to further approach it. What are the advantages or disadvantages of the centralized or decentralized approach -- and are there any other common possibilities that I've yet to think of or encounter?

Comment: As a starting point I'd recommend watching quill18creates playlist, where he creates a clone of Rimworld(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S5S4RN2x7hc&list=PLbghT7MmckI4_VM5q3va043FgAwRim6yX&index=16)

Answer (score 0):

Centralized lists are a timesaver - instead of querrying each jobgiver/workdoer you get them registered for a quick access/sort/filter.

In that light, I'd frame your choice a bit differently - "**jobs list** vs. **workers list**".

From that, having both lists, you can naturally evolve into a "matchmaking" system, that will pick best jobs for most suitable workers (e.g. with Hungarian Algorithm that does optimized matching). Simplest approach is - if you have more jobs that workers, let workers pick jobs they prefer. Or vice versa.